# Stripping server side comments in Python

Tags: python, html, django, comments

In JSP:

```
<%-- Comments removed in server --%>
```

What is the equivalent when I run in Python/Django ?!?

I don't want the HTML comments visible in the client side...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{% comment %}

add your comment here :-)

{% endcomment %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Django template comment block http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#comment

They won't be displayed on the client side, but you will see it when editing templates.